# php stat_session no such file error when save path is subdir

Tags: php, session

Very strange error :

I've my `/tmp` dir owned by `root:root`, and mode `777`
then into it, there is `/tmp/php` same owner, same mode.

when I set `session.save_path = "/tmp"` everything work well,

but when I set `session.save_path = "/tmp/php"`, I get this error in phpmyadmin :

```
Warning in ./libraries/session.inc.php#101
session_start(): open(/tmp/php/sess_ebaq353ndgtiiljg2ifqe6oes1r5ljar, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

Backtrace

./libraries/session.inc.php#101: session_start()
./libraries/common.inc.php#352: require(./libraries/session.inc.php)
./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Does the `tmp/php` folder exist? **edit: sorry, missed where you stated that in the question**... I assume when you say "...I set `ession.save_path =`..." it's a typo in the question and you meant to say `session.save_path`.

Comment: "then into it, there is /tmp/php same owner, same mode."

Comment: yes, ession[...] was a typo sorry

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you restarted your web server.

Also, `/tmp/` does not always mean the directory `/tmp/`. Check `/var/tmp/`,`/var/php_sessions/` or for `/tmp/private/` and try putting your php directory in there.

I'm not too familiar with nginx php-fpm pools, but it sounds like it may have it's own setting. See [this page](http://www.smerret.com/computers/linux/nginx/nginx-with-php-fpm) and look for the section concerning `php_admin_value[session.save_path]`.

Finally, you could troubleshoot this in reverse - you can use `find` to see where your session files are stored:
`find / -name 'sess_*'`

This will search the hard drive volumes for the session files and you can then search your configs for the tmp file path to see what is setting the unexpected /tmp directory.

Comment: where should the prefix defined (or the alias) ?

Comment: server restarted (nginx + php-fpm), no changement. neither creating /var/tmp/php (root:root,777) and others

Comment: Nop, this is not the problem, /tmp points to /tmp. Maybe it's something about the "auto clean up" of /tmp : on reboot, /tmp/php is removed, but what was weird is that if I create this directory before starting php, there is still the error... Anyway I just changed the directory to /var/php/sessions thus, it's no longer a problem. Nevertheless, I'm a bit curious about the reason it didn't work Oo